# Getting an exception thrown when I try to access private key from key container

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to access the private key from a key container and then use it to decrypt a previously encrypted byte[] message. My code appears capable of encrypting that byte[], but when I try to decrypt it, I get the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I am using C# in Visual Studios.
My main function looks like this:

```
try
        {
            string testValue = "TestKeyContainer";
            string message = "This is the test message!";

            UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

            byte[] originalData = ByteConverter.GetBytes(message);
            byte[] encryptedData;
            byte[] decryptedData;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = null;

            //Create a public-private key pair and store them in a key container.
            MakeAndSaveKey(testValue);

            //[Attempt to] retrieve the key from the container
            rsa = GetKeyFromContainer(testValue);

            //Read message
            Console.WriteLine("Reading the test message... *ahem*...\n{0}", ByteConverter.GetString(originalData));

            //Encrypt, then read message
            encryptedData = encrypt(originalData, rsa);
            Console.WriteLine("Reading the encrypted message...\n....\n{0}", ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedData));

            //Decrypt, then read message
            decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData, rsa);
            Console.WriteLine("Reading the decrypted message...\n{0}", ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData));

            //Delete key from the container
            //DeleteKey("TestKeyContainer");
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

DeleteKey(string) being unfinished, and thus commented out. Code for MakeAndSaveKey(string) is:

```
private static void MakeAndSaveKey(string containerName)
{
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;
    return; 
}
```

GetKeyFromContainer(string) is:

```
private static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetKeyFromContainer(string containerName)
    {
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
        return rsa;
    }
```

It should be noted that MakeAndSaveKey and GetKeyFromContainer are literally just a C# translation of Microsoft's code from their [How to: Store Asymmetric Keys in a Key Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container).

The code for encrypt(byte[], RSACryptoServiceProvider) is:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] message, RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
    {
        using (rsa)
        {
            message = RSAEncrypt(message, rsa.ExportParameters(false), false);
        }

        return message;
    }
```

And for decrypt(byte[], RSACryptoServiceProvider):

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message, RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
    {
        using (rsa)
        {
            try
            {
                message = RSADecrypt(message, rsa.ExportParameters(true), false);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't decrypt the message. \n:ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
```

The program outputs the following before it stalls:

> Reading the test message... *ahem*...
>
> This is the test message!
>
> Reading the encrypted message...
>
> ....
>
> ??????????????????????????u?????????????????=?????????s???????h?

, except that the '=' has three lines instead of two. I just don't know where to find that symbol.

After that, I get the exception described at the top of this post. Specifically, it points to the statement

```
message = RSADecrypt(message, rsa.ExportParameters(true), false);
```

from decrypt(byte[], RSACryptoServiceProvider) definition. Does anybody know why this is happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: It seems you're doing a `using (rsa)` on an object you're given through parameters, this is probably the reason. Only the method/object that initially constructed this object should dispose of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (resource)
{
    // do something
}
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
finally
{
    if (resource!= null)
        resource.Dispose();
}
```

So it means that `decrypt` tries to use already disposed object. 
If you hold the `resource`(s) in your own container, it means you are managing it by yourself and you should not use `using`. Remove the use of `using` and make sure to dispose all the resources manually when done. It should work.

Comment: Thank you, the "using (rsa)" definitely seems to be have been the problem. It works now!